# Querying mongoDB using the mlab data API with Ion returning the message: "Please provide a valid API key"

Tags: android, mongodb, mlab, android-ion

I'm trying to do a simple query on my mongoDB database using the mlab data API. Making a GET request using the browser works fine, but when I try to make the same request using [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion), it keeps returning the message: "Please provide a valid API key."

So here I am trying to find a document with the fields username=user, and password=password:

```
Ion.with(this)
.load("https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/dbtest9238/collections/users?q={\"username\": \"user\", \"password\": \"password\"}&apiKey=" + apiKey)
.asJsonObject().setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
   @Override
   public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
       // do stuff with the result or error
   }
});
```

I'm able to make POST requests with no problems, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem was that I was using unsafe characters in my URL ('{', '}', and ':').
Replacing those with the URL encoded versions solved the problem.